# FlexBasis on React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a Views with a flexBasis percentage value, but I can't be able to render this in React Native.
According to documentation, the Flex-Basis property accept % values.
How can I perform it into React?
Thanks

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between',}}>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'0.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.4)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'10%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.5)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'50%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.6)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'3%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.7)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'2.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.8)'}}></View>         
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'1.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.5)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'2%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.4)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'28.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.3)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'0.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.2)'}}></View>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'1.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.1)'}}></View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set flex value on the surrounding View you will be able to see it

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'0.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.4)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'10%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.5)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'50%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.6)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'3%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.7)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'2.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 139, 196, 0.8)'}}></View>         
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'1.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.5)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'2%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.4)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'28.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.3)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'0.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.2)'}}></View>
  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, flexBasis:'1.5%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(226, 7, 23, 0.1)'}}></View>
</View>
```

[image: rendered output]